# Does async await use Windows Messages to return control to the UI thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, async-await

I still don't fully understand how async/await works. Every Internet post tells me something about a SynchronizationContext and such, but I still don't get how that wakes up the UI thread.

Imagine I use `await` from the UI thread and control shall return back there (`.ConfigureAwait(true)`).

My task will be executed on a threadpool thread. In the meanwhile, the UI stays responsive, which means it is in the message loop. I'm lazy, not moving the mouse or anything, so the UI thread is blocking in `GetMesssage()`.

Will .NET (the SynchronizationContext or whatever) at some point send or post a message to the UI thread so that it is woken up? If so, which message would that be?

Typically, Windows messages will be dispatched into a function call. How does .NET manage to call an arbitrary method (the remainder of code that follows `await`)?

Comment: await generate state mahine ... wndProc has parameters ...  you can then post instance of this state machine and call next() (or whatever from it) ... *which message would that be?* you can send app specific message ... in old days you du `#define WM_MY_MESSAGE (WM_USER+1)` and that's it (first number in user message "pool")

Comment: @Selvin: that's how it *can* be done and how I imagine it is done. But is it done that way by Microsoft's implementation? How do they make sure that they don't use the same message as WM_MY_MESSAGE?

Comment: there are multiple different implementation ...depends on technology ... ..fx in winform `SynchronizationContext` implementation using `Control.Invoke` (you can go and check Control source) ... *How do they make sure that they don't use the same message* prolly using `RegisterWindowMessage`

Comment: When you await a method, you setup a scheduled task (unit of work). The scheduler generates a timed event. It's similar to the [CreateTimerQueueTimer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/threadpoollegacyapiset/nf-threadpoollegacyapiset-createtimerqueuetimer) (see also [What's New in Synchronization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/what-s-new-in-synchronization)), it's called [TimerQueueTimer](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Timer.cs,448)

Comment: The State Machine is setup (saving state at the moment of the call), then the method is enqueued in a MethodTable which binds the method to the compiler-generated metadata, [through the EEClass](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2005/may/net-framework-internals-how-the-clr-creates-runtime-objects). When the Task is completed, the timer, which is initialized with the address of the callback, resumes the execution from the address specified. There are no  messages sent to the top-level classes involved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we are talking about WinForms and its main thread, then yes, the windows messages are used.

The TPL (Task Parallel Library) uses `SynchronizationContext.Post()` to handle continuations of the tasks ([Line 416 [Github]](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/b80048efbdd1d547efafefe8667d82de9a074850/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/TaskContinuation.cs#L416))

When you capture the `SynchronizationContext` in the WinForms app main thread, the context will be `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext` class ([line 90 [Github]](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/blob/da7bb656430a3990534237d1418822688368932c/src/System.Windows.Forms/src/System/Windows/Forms/WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.cs#L90)).

Internally, this synchronization context uses the `Control.BeginInvoke()` to pass control to the main thread ([line 90 [Github]](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/blob/da7bb656430a3990534237d1418822688368932c/src/System.Windows.Forms/src/System/Windows/Forms/WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.cs#L90)).

And finally, the `Control.BeginInvoke()` uses the `PostMessage()` ([line 6923 [Github]](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/blob/da7bb656430a3990534237d1418822688368932c/src/System.Windows.Forms/src/System/Windows/Forms/Control.cs#L6923)).

The message used is registered in [line 6911 [Github]](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/blob/da7bb656430a3990534237d1418822688368932c/src/System.Windows.Forms/src/System/Windows/Forms/Control.cs#L6911) and looks like `<SomeVersion>_ThreadCallbackMessage` (and specifically for Net FW 4.7.2 and later (up to the time of writing this answer) - `WindowsForms12_ThreadCallbackMessage`) and then handled in the `WndProc` [line 13275 [Github]](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/blob/da7bb656430a3990534237d1418822688368932c/src/System.Windows.Forms/src/System/Windows/Forms/Control.cs#L13275) in very straightforward way - just dequeue a list of callbacks stored before the message was sent, then execute those callbacks ([line 6568](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/blob/da7bb656430a3990534237d1418822688368932c/src/System.Windows.Forms/src/System/Windows/Forms/Control.cs#L6568) and after a few calls the real execution goes to [line 6489](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/blob/da7bb656430a3990534237d1418822688368932c/src/System.Windows.Forms/src/System/Windows/Forms/Control.cs#L6489)).

In conjunction with `async/await`, the stored callback is just a call to the `async/await` state machine (mentioned in the comments), which then calls the desired part of the code.

Note: This is only valid for WinForms and for the current implementation and may be changed in the future.

Note 2: the test code with the manual message loop to play with this mechanism may be found [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/289663/proving-that-a-window-message-is-being-sent-by-async-await/289721#289721). It is also the full stack trace of the continuation handling (on the side of the finished task's thread) shown there.

Comment: *And finally, the `Control.Invoke` uses the `PostMessage()`*: no, it doesn't. Check a second time

Comment: @Jimi, can you please explain this further? As I can see, when called from the non-main thread, it will definitely use the `PostMessage()`.

Comment: What I mean is that just saying that *it calls `PostMessage()`* is not correct. That's what `BeginInvoke()` does. `Invoke()` is synchronous, so `PostMessage()` won't make sense. But, since `SendMessage()` cannot be used here, then there's a synchronized WaitHandle. In other words, don't make someone think that `Control.Invoke()` somehow becomes asynchronous when called from a Thread other than the UI Thread. It would be a bad mistake (there's a complete explanation of the entire process in the notes found in `MarshaledInvoke()`)

Comment: BTW, since this is about async/await functionality (now that I've actually read the question :), `Control.Invoke()` / `BeginInvoke()` are not used

Comment: I agree that the `async/await` concept itself has absolutely nothing to do with `Control.Invoke()'.  But the question was specifically about "how control is passed from the thread pool thread to the UI thread in WinForms". And as far as I know, for now the current implementation of WinForms works as described in the answer. Did I miss something?

Comment: Well, the question is *Does async await use Windows Messages to return control to the UI thread?*, so, no, those methods are not involved and no message is sent

Comment: The general idea is that `await` uses `SynchronizationContext`, and `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext` uses custom Win32 messages that act as function pointers / delegates to resume the `async` method. And this is correct. There are a few specifics that are wrong (e.g,. `Invoke` doesn't use `PostMessage`), but that's beside the point: [`await` uses `Post` and not `Send` (and therefore `BeginInvoke` instead of `Invoke`)](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/b80048efbdd1d547efafefe8667d82de9a074850/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/TaskContinuation.cs#L416).

Comment: @Serg: I debugged it, so there's a call stack available at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/289721/36647 and we can clean up all the confusion and misunderstandings. Let's agree that we were all wrong. You were wrong by saying Invoke() is used. Jimi was wrong by saying BeginInvoke() is *not* used. And I had no idea at all, right from the beginning. And finally, Stephen Cleary was absolutely right once more.

Comment: Maybe you want to edit your answer to make it fully correct, then I'm happy to accept it.

Comment: Yes, I have corrected and extended the answer. Thanks Stephen for pointing out the missing link and to the mixed up `Invoke/InvokeAsync` and thanks Thomas for experiment with WinDbg.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you all. I understood so much in the past two days.

Answer (score 1):

> Will .NET (the SynchronizationContext or whatever) at some point send or post a message to the UI thread so that it is woken up?

Yes, in WinForms, it does. The WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext [will use the `.BeginInvoke()`](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/blob/dd5ae276be5f5e8c2203fd5f07bdc725a9891945/src/System.Windows.Forms/src/System/Windows/Forms/WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.cs#L89) functionality of Control which posts a message.

> If so, which message would that be?

It is a registered window message, i.e. a special message registered via Win32's [RegisterWindowMessage()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerwindowmessagea) function.
Such messages are in the range 0xC000 to 0xFFFF. [Raymond Chen calls 0xC000 MAXINTATOM](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080429-00/?p=22543), in case you want a name for that magic number.

You can see the [registration of that message](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/blob/da7bb656430a3990534237d1418822688368932c/src/System.Windows.Forms/src/System/Windows/Forms/Control.cs#L6911) in the source code.

You can register the same message yourself using P/Invoke

```cs
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern uint RegisterWindowMessage(string lpString);
```

with `"WindowsForms12_ThreadCallbackMessage"` as the string (for .NET Framework 4.7.2) and get the same message ID back.

To see everything in action using a debugger, check [this code on CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/289663/36647) and don't forget to implement the enhancements mentioned there.

Comment: I still insist that async / await does not use `[Control].BeginInvoke()` and it doesn't use messages, for its functionality. Not an async / await thing (not all platforms have a SynchronizationContext). I'm going to explain my point, this time (as soon as I have that time available)

Comment: @Jimi: I'll be very glad to read your answer. Since we have [this comment from Stephen Cleary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78028901/does-async-await-use-windows-messages-to-return-control-to-the-ui-thread/78052520?noredirect=1#comment137598148_78028982), it'll be somewhat difficult to convince me. Nevertheless, I'm eager to learn all the time and I'll make sure to understand your point.